# Find the subgraph with the max weighted average length of edges in a complete bipartite graph

Tags: discrete-optimization, np-complete, bipartite-graphs

I have a complete bipartite graph. Each edge of the graph has a length $l$ and weight $w$.

My goal is to find a complete subgraph (a subgraph that is a complete bipartite graph itself) of this bipartite graph such that the weighted average length ($\sum wl/\sum w$) of the edges in the subgraph is maximized.

(Edit: an additional constraint of the subgraph is that there is one given edge, say edge $ij$, and its two vertices $i$ and $j$, that must be included in the subgraph.)

Any ideas on how to solve this problem? Or is it a NP-hard problem? Thanks.

Comment: Which subgraphs are allowed?  If it is meant to be a difficult problem, then presumably selecting only one of the longest edges is ruled out somehow.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out, made an edit on the constraints of the subgraph.

Comment: Yes, by "complete subgraph" I mean "a subgraph that is complete bipartite graph".